# Forcing ndk-build to include C++ libraries

Tags: android, c++, ndk-build

I have an application where all components are first assembled as static libraries and then those libraries are repacked to shared libraries. So the module(s) doing `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` have empty `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`. With the way the components are laid out and composed, it makes sense and must remain that way.

However, the library for `APP_STL` only gets added if there is a C++ source (recognized by extension, which can be overridden with `LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION`) in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`. So the standard library does not get added and the final object does not link, because the component libraries do need it.

Is there a way to force NDK to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [undocumented](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html) variable `LOCAL_HAS_CPP` that does it:

```
LOCAL_HAS_CPP := true
```

It is relatively new though. It is in the most recent NDK r16b (as of Mar 2018), but not in the r12b version we used until now.